Android Studio Jellyfish cannot run Java loop
This may sound CRAZY but I recently upgraded to AS Jellyfish in a project which I have been developing for some time. Now when I try to run the following loop (as a test) the emulator shows the Toast message as far as i = 3. Then NOTHING. Even running on a connected device I get the same result ?
public void newGen(){
int i=0;
while (i<=10)
{

    Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this, "the value is " + i, LENGTH_LONG).show();

    i++;
}

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Paul

instead of showing a toast just use a log message, if you see that all your log messages are showing in the logcat then its no a problem with the loop

Does this answer your question? Is there a limit to the amount of displayable Toasts?

Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try but this simple loop with a toast was created to test what I saw in another bit of more complex coding where it became apparent that the loop was not excuting completely. To give the full story it seemed to be working except the programme went into a repeating loop. I closed the run. On re-opening I saw the reason for the repeating loop and corrected the issue. Since then my loops stop prematurely.
